# Multidumentional array

Tags: php

```
$var = Array
(
[NAME] => Array
(
[0] => JHOUTALA
[1] => TIMESQUARE
[2] => COX-KALATOLI 
[3] => A.K.KHAN 
[4] => CTG DAMPARA
)

[TIME] => Array
(
[0] => 09:45 PM
[1] => 09:45 PM
[2] => 10:00 PM
[3] => 02:15 AM
[4] => 02:15 AM
)
);
```

How to convert this array?

```
<select>
<option> 09:45 PM JHOUTALA</option>
<option> 09:45 PM TIMESQUARE</option>
<option> 10:00 PM COX-KALATOLI</option>
<option> 02:15 AM A.K.KHAN </option>
<option> 02:15 AM CTG DAMPARA </option>
</select> "
```

Comment: Very nice. Did you have a question?

Comment: Maybe "how to convert this array" was the question? But still unclear.

Comment: The result doesn't look like an array to me

Comment: Writing code would be a good start. We're here to help, not do your job for you.

Comment: First if you want to export the array for coding purpose you have to use var_export($yourarray); instead of var_dump or print_r

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correct you need to concatinate the values from TIME and NAME

if their count of values are same then you can use `for` to iterate.
Example:

```
$count = count($var['NAME']);
$html = "<select>\n";
for ($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    $html .= "<option>".$var['TIME'][$i]." ".$var['NAME'][$i]."</option>\n";
}
$html .= "</select>";
```

Note that this is only IF the counts of these 2 dimensions are same.

The expected result will be in the $html variavble. and you can print it.